# Why are my custom laravel artisan commands not available in production environment

Tags: php, laravel

I have just installed a laravel app on the "to-be" production server (1and1 shared linux server).

With the same codebase as on my development server (Ubuntu 14.04 lts) my custom artisan commands are not available (php5.5 artisan list) on the production server.

I have done composer dump-autoload already.
I have also checked the app/start/artisan.php file and that is OK and is executed.
I have checked the app/config/production/app.php for the service providers and they seem to be all right.

I have also spent the better part of the day here on stackoverflow to find a solution, but without much success.

My Laravel version is:  4.1.28

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: What happens when you try to run a command ?

Comment: All commands like migrate etc. work as usual. Since I do not see my command in the list, I receive a: [InvalidArgumentException]                                 
  There are no commands defined in the "myCommand" namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting no errors, you probably don't have the same codebase in production because, if resolve commands in your artisan.php file:

```
Artisan::resolve('CommandName');
```

And Laravel doesn't have access to this class, it will raise an exception:

```
"ReflectionException","message":"Class CommandName does not exist"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. In using: Artisan::add(new myCommand); in app/start/artisan.php

Comment: Is this code in your production server? Have you checked the file to see if it is there?

Comment: Yes, the file is there. and so is the command in app/commands and the class loader in vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php

Comment: @haemhweg: No unfortunately not yet. I have already asked the IRC channel of Laravel, Twitter, etc.  
I was somewhat glad that I am at least not alone, when I saw your post just now :-). Hope we find something soon. I will certainly keep you posted.

Comment: Yeah, kinda strange. Debugging in production environment yielded that app actually "visits" the source files where command is defined `app/commands/MyCommand.php` and where it is registered `app/start/artisan.php`, but command doesn't even appear in command list.

Comment: @haemhweg: Yes, strange indeed. Till that is solved I have "packaged" my commands following these two articles: 
http://culttt.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-laravel-4-package/ 
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456771/laravel-4-deploy-custom-artisan-command-in-package

Comment: OK, actually I found the problem. It has to deal with version of php binary we are running. You can check it by typing `php -v`. On my local server it is `cli`, stands for 'command line interface', on my production server it is `cgi-fcgi`, stands for e. g. web applications. So when running, for example, `php artisan list`, application thinks we are not in command line and acts as if we are viewing site. You can test your commands in production server by putting `return true;` first in `Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php@runningInConsole`. You might try to hard code env detection.